# Space in header xml working with php

Tags: php, xml

and i have it

```
<match>
      <Bet OddsType="01">
        <Odds OutCome="1">9.0</Odds>
        <Odds OutCome="x">8.5</Odds>
        <Odds OutCome="2">6.75</Odds>
      </Bet>
      <Bet OddsType="02">
        <Odds OutCome="1">2.0</Odds>
        <Odds OutCome="2">3.5</Odds>        
      </Bet>
....

</match>
```

so in php through i call the web page with `$xml = simplexml_load_file(` and next i try to get

```
foreach($xml->Match->Bet as $Bet){

$Bet->Odds[0]//for first time it give me 9.0, for second 2.0..etc
```

here i no have problem, but i need obtain the value of OutCome, but i cant when i do a print_r to $Bet, i get  `Array ( [OddsType] => 02 ) [Odds] => Array ( [0] => 9.0 [1] => 8.5 [2] =>6.75))....` and OutCome disappears

please i need help for obtain the value of OutCome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) to access the `OutCome` attribute.  For example:

```
foreach($xml->Match->Bet as $Bet){

   $attr = $Bet->Odds[0]->attributes();
   var_dump($attr['OutCome']);
}
```